# How to replace .live() method with .on() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Hei.. I have a function to load more news. Since jquery-1.9.1.min.js this function was working alright, but now I have to replace it with .on() method and I still can't get it work.

Here is the code:

```
  // Load more news feed
  $(function(){
      var page = 1;
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "data.php",
          data: "page=profile&get_news_feed=true",
          dataType:'json',
          success: function(data){
              $("#the_news_feed").html(data.news_feed);
              if(page <= data.total_pages){
                  $("#the_news_feed").after('<button id="load_more_feed" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" style="width: 100%;margin-top:10px">Load More</button>');
              }
          }
      });
      $("#load_more_feed").live("click", function(){
          var next = page+=1;
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "data.php",
              data: "page=profile&get_news_feed=true&page_num="+next,
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(data){
                  $("#the_news_feed").append(data.news_feed);
                  if(next == data.total_pages){
                      $("#load_more_feed").remove();
                  } else {
                      $("#load_more_feed").html("Load More");
                  }
              },
              beforeSend: function(){
                  $("#load_more_feed").html("Loading...");
              }
          });
      });
  });
```

I tryed to replace:

```
$("#load_more_feed").live("click", function()
```

with

```
$("#the_news_feed").on("click", "load_more_feed", function()
```

but I still can't get it work. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

I display this function with id="news_feed" so here was the problem

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="news_feed">
  <div id="the_news_feed"></div>
</div>
```

Final solution is `$("#news_feed").on("click", "load_more_feed", function()`

Thank you guys!

Comment: are u sure its working? im pretty sure it wont :) anyway good for u :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you're missing the `#` in the id selector.

```
$("#the_news_feed").on("click", "load_more_feed", function()
```

must be

```
$("#the_news_feed").on("click", "#load_more_feed", function()
```

assuming `#the_news_feed` is the parent of `#load_more_feed`.

**EDIT :**

From your code, you're appending this `#loadmore` button *after* `#the_news_feed`, so this obviously will not work. Try changing it to this :

```
$(document).on("click", "#load_more_feed", function()
```

This will bind the click to the `document`, which will always exist. Alternatively, you could bind it to `#load_more_feed` closest static parent, like an element which exists when you load your page and not dynamically created.

Comment: Ok...I found it..I will update my question and provide a mistake

Comment: Final solution:  `$("#news_feed").on("click", "load_more_feed", function()`